# Building projects in Delphi 10 Seattle on windows 7 - do they work in windows 10?

Tags: delphi, windows-7, windows-10, delphi-10-seattle

Is windows 10 backwards compatible for exe files built by delphi 10 in windows7?

My attempts to provoke crashes in windows 10 have all failed, but i cant find any documentation to back up my theory, can anyone help?

Comment: EXEs neither depend on a Windows version, nor on Windows itself. What has this question to do with "Delphi 7"? Compiling a 64bit EXE and trying to run it on 32bit will never work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 up to now will run any cleanly written 32 bit Windows executable. It does not matter whether the executable was compiled on Windows 7 or Windows 10.

(For what it's worth: Even Programs written with Delphi 6 and compiled on Windows 95 will work under Windows 10, as long as they behave. That is mostly: Don't write to c:\program files or HKLM in the registry. They will not be able to detect the correct Windows version or use some newer Windows features though.)

Answer (score 2):

Compiling Windows based programs using Delphi on different Windows versions will not affect build results. Same source code will always be built into same end application regardless of which version of Windows you used to run Delphi environment on.

You can even run your Delphi on 32 bit Windows and compile 64 bit application with it if you wish so. Granted you won't be able to debug such application since you can't run 64 bit program on 32 bit OS.

In fact I have heard some people are running Delphi on Linux inside Wine environment while developing Windows applications and it still works.